# How can a bookstore obtain my KDP paperbacks wholesale?

Tags: publishing

I've done some digging and found advice on how you can enable expanded distribution on Amazon as an author, but I've tried to look up how the bookstore I am associated with can obtain KDP copies of my titles, wholesale at wholesale prices.

The biggest bit I've been able to find so far is that Amazon publishes wholesale KDP titles via IngramSpark (on terms that may be a deterrent to some bookstores from purchasing things that way), and recommend publishing your work directly on IngramSpark so you can publish it on terms bookstores are less likely to be bothered by.

Searches such as 'site:ingramspark.com "C.J.S. Hayward in Under 99 Pages"', 'site:ingramspark.com 979-8485392727', searches including 'Amazon' etc. do not seem to turn up anything promising.

How can a bookstore which so desires purchase my KDP paper titles wholesale?

Comment: KDP is Kindle Direct Publishing. Such questions should probably be addressed to Amazon.